# SQL Calculate percentage change for multiple rows vs one row

Tags: sql, select

I need to calculate percentage change for multiple rows vs one row. Example below. Please advise on a simple SQL select.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods.  One simple method is a `join`:

```
select t.*,
       (t.value - t2.value) * 100.0 / t2.value
from t join
     t t2
     on t2.date = '20200731';
```

Answer (score 1):

You could cross join the table on a subquery vs that row:

```
SELECT      t.time, t.value, (t.value - s.value) / s.value * 100 AS change
FROM        mytable t
CROSS JOIN  (SELECT time, value
             FROM   mytable
             WHERE  time = 20200731 -- Assumption: this returns only one row
            ) s
```